# Form Closes When it Shouldn't

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Forms in my application. They way I call `Form 2` is like this:

Form 1:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = new System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult();
    Add_Link addLink = new Add_Link();
    result=addLink.ShowDialog();

    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Form 2:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if(validURL(txtSubLink.Text))
    {
        HyperLink add = new HyperLink(txtSubLink.Text,txtSubText.Text,"URL");
        this.build = add;                 
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Valid URL Needed! " + txtSubLink.Text, "ERROR");
    }             
}
```

My problem is if the user clicks the `Add` button, the error message shows(because the data is invalid or the textboxes are empty) **BUT** it closes the form. I only want the user to close the form and pass the data back if the two textboxes contain the proper data. If the two textboxes don't contain the proper data **OR** is empty, when the user clicks Add, the error message should show, and the `Form 2` should remain open, How do I get that to happen...?

Comment: I don't see the code that triggers the form closure... I'm puzzled

Comment: @miniBill - In the first if statement on form 2 it closes it regardless or error or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect your `btnAdd` has its `DialogResult` property set to `OK`. Unset that, and then add `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` in your event handler when you're satisfied with the input.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(validURL(txtSubLink.Text))
    {
         HyperLink add = new HyperLink(txtSubLink.Text,txtSubText.Text,"URL");
         this.build = add;
         this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Valid URL Needed! " + txtSubLink.Text, "ERROR");
    }

}
```

Comment: Nevermind, your right. I had put this.btnAdd.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK, instead of this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok. It works now. Thanks